# Using JAVA 9 G1GC, System.gc () not executed when application under load. Why?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

Recently we have upgraded to JAVA9 and decided to try G1GC algorithm. Then given load to the application and observed the behaviour of it
1)  Full GC has not executed, even after consuming 80% of memory (under load)
2)  Full GC (System.gc()) executed only in idle state but its dose when application in idle state

Here is my JVM config:
    -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m 
    -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m 
    -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128M 
    -server 
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -verbose:gc 
    -XX:+PrintCodeCache 
    -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=600000 
    -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=600000 
    -Djava.awt.headless=true 
    -Xlog:gc*"

## java -version

java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

Why Full GC (System.gc()) not executed when the application is under load?
Why Full GC has not executed, even after consuming 80% of memory?

[Graph of Heap Usage after GC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaRcn.jpg)

Click here for    [Jboss_console.log](https://ufile.io/29lo3)